# Create scroll view of view controllers like iOS app selection panel

Tags: ios

I am trying to create scroll view displaying different view controllers as we can see on the native iOS app selection panel ( displayed by double tapping the home button ).

I was thinking about creating a view controller with a `UIScrollView` and adding the other view controllers as children of the first view controller and placing their views in the scroll view.

I am wondering if there is an easier way to achieve what I am trying to do ?

Comment: You could look at something like iCarousel

Comment: Yes ! That's exactly the kind of stuff I was looking for, thanks !